# Is it secure to expose an endpoint that encrypts using a protected symmetric key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric, aes-gcm

I want to simplify a process where a non-privileged person needs to encrypt data with a symmetric key (AES-GCM) and give me the result. Non-privileged simply means the person has no access to the encryption key.

With asymmetric cryptos like RSA and EC, giving anyone the public key is of course part of the whole idea, but with symmetric cryptos, the privileged party is the only one who can decrypt *or* encrypt, obviously.

To simplify my workflow I'm considering setting up a simple HTTP endpoint that encrypts a given string using my private symmetric key and returns the result. Something like

```
GET somewhere.com/encrypt?keyId=foo&data=Hello%20world
```

which would return something like

```
{
  "keyId": "foo",
  "encryptedData": "xxxxxx"
}
```

Behind the scenes, this could be an AWS Lambda function using a KMS key designated by `keyId` to encrypt `data` and return the encrypted result.

However, I want to be sure this is not a security problem in itself. For example, is there a known attack where someone can find out the key material for AES from encrypting billions of strings and then processing the source strings and their encrypted counterparts? In other words, would exposing an encryption endpoint be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using symmetric crypto where asymmetric would fit the purpose better.

If it needs to be symmetric for some reason, it would be more secure to have the service itself send you the encrypted result if possible, instead of returning it to the untrusted party.

The way you proposed would allow a straightforward chosen plaintext attack (the proposed service *is* nothing else but a chosen plaintext facility). While AES-GCM as your tag suggests is not practically vulnerable to chosen plaintext afaik (*others more knowledgable in crypto please correct me if this is not true*), this might still be a bad idea, as

1. having an oracle to use the encryption key might cause issues elsewhere in your architecture (or not, depending on what happens in other parts of your system, but this likely would cause more systemic vulnerabilities), and
2. though maybe unlikely, new attacks might be found against AES.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea does not have a security flaw in itself. The feasibility of a brute-force attack (where someone finds out the key by doing billions of attempts) depends on the AES key size you use. A key size of 256 bits is recommended, as this would require on-average 2^256 attempts, which is infeasible.

Sidenote: [Evervault](https://evervault.com/) provides services/SDKs for exactly this use case. They have a decent free tier so might be good to consider using them instead of implementing the encryption API yourself (and risking a security mistake).

Comment: A key size of 128 is also recommended.

Comment: I believe with the rise of quantum computing, a key size of 128 is no longer recommended, as a quantum computer would be able to brute-force it in 2^64 operations, which is deemed insecure. Curious to hear your thoughts on that though!

Comment: That's more hype than reality. [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102671/is-aes-128-quantum-safe) is a good discussion.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for sharing that thread. It's very insightful